# Drawable , Layouts, etc... in a DLL?

Tags: xamarin.android

Is it possible in monodroid to have Drawables, Layouts, etc... (I mean resources) in a DLL? The problem is that I have created a project that generates a DLL but it doesn't build the project structure a regular android application project builds. Is there any possibility to accomplish this? Where should I move drawables, etc... in a dll?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in the current version of Mono for Android. [This post](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodroid/2012-May/010402.html) on the mailing list provides some more details about it. It's on the roadmap to get added in a future version, but I don't think they've given a timeline on it.